# Make the same curve in SVG and CANVAS

Tags: canvas, svg, d3.js

I have problem with create the same curve in SVG and CANVAS. I have graph d3js force layout, and in force tick method I prepare values for SVG curve:

```
                        link.attr("d", function (d) {
                        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
                            normX = dx / ((dr != 0) ? dr : 1),
                            normY = dy / ((dr != 0) ? dr : 1),
                            sourcePadding = d.left ? 50 : 5,
                            targetPadding = d.right ? 50 : 5,
                            sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX),
                            sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY),
                            targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX),
                            targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

                        return "M" +
                            sourceX + "," +
                            sourceY + "A" +
                            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
                            targetX + "," +
                            targetY;});
```

How can I create the same curve in CANVAS ? I try this, but this no work :

```
                    edges.forEach(function (d) {
                        // Draw a line from source to target.
                        context.beginPath();
                        context.fillStyle = d.color;
                       // context.quadraticCurveTo(288, 0, 388, 150);
                        context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
                        context.quadraticCurveTo(d.source.y, d.source.y - 50, d.target.x, d.target.y);
                       // context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
                        context.stroke();
                    });
```

Thanks for help !

There is jdFidlle SVG / CANVAS : [JsFiddle SVG on the left canvas on right](http://jsfiddle.net/Klainer/ppgtsb1r/1/)

**Solved, solution is here:** [SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/Klainer/ppgtsb1r/4/)
But I have problem with arrows, on the end of the curve. Can anybody help me with this ? I think there is mayby problem with raduis. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The SVG quadratic curve command is Q, not A (which is an elliptical arc). An arc in canvas would be drawn using [arc or arcTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

Comment: Ok thank you, but how to correct map SVG to CANVAS arc function. I try this:  context.arc(d.source.x, d.source.y, dr, 0, 0,1, 0); no work

Comment: Specifying a startAngle and endAngle both 0 won't get you anything. Try arcTo rather than arc.

Comment: Still no work: context.arcTo(d.source.x, d.source.y, d.target.x, d.target.y, 30);

Comment: Create a jsfiddle we can run then.